# Can Visual Studio 2010 do Code Coverage analysis on F# modules?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, code-coverage

Though I ask it to, Visual Studio 2010 does not appear to generate code coverage statistics for my F# modules. The unit tests are Ms Tests written in C#, so are run natively by Visual Studio, and execute cleanly. But there does not appear to be any coverage information created for the F# library being tested. The C# libraries involved are analyzed just fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The thing to double check is that the F# binary is being instrumented correctly. IIRC, there was a bug in the VS code coverage tools that prevented them from understanding ".tail" IL op codes.

Answer (score 4):

This [link](http://bloggemdano.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-mstest-with-f.html) describes using the VS testing system with F#. You do it pretty much the same way as with C#.

The downside is that apparently the VS IDE won't automatically pick it up -- I believe you need to run from the command line using [mstest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490%28VS.80%29.aspx).exe.

Edit: Oh, another cool thing with F#, is [FsCheck](http://www.codeplex.com/fscheck), an automatic testing tool for F#, is basically a port of Haskell's QuickCheck. It allows you to provide a specification of the program, in the form of properties that the functions or methods should satisfy, and FsCheck tests that the properties hold in a large number of randomly generated cases.

also [fsunit](http://code.google.com/p/fsunit/) and [fstest](http://www.codeplex.com/FsTest)

Comment: thanks for the good links & pointers, though this question was about code coverage!